Is it okay to delete "default" service account in particular namespace?
I was confused by one of CKS exam question, it was asked to find and delete the service account which are not in use.
There were no pods using "default" service account, was I then supposed to delete it as well?

The answer is yes, you can delete the "default" service account if not in use.

Right. I was in a dilemma whether I should or should not. To check if default SA is used or not, we should just check the pods or I am missing something? kubectl get pods -n NAMESPACE -o yaml | grep -i serviceaccount !!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

It should be fine, but it will be automatically be recreated, and if you create a pod (directly or through the workload API) in that same namespace the new default service account will be assigned to it (provided that the pod doesn't explicitly has a different service account configured).
Keep in mind that if you have existing pods runnings and those pods talk to the kube-apiserver, they won't be able to talk to it until they are recreated since the service account credentials will not be valid.

The doc says whenever you create a new namespace it creates that SA. But it also says if you delete it, then cluster will automatically recreate it? does it happen immediately or it happens when a pod is being created and if it sees no default SA is there then it creates it?!! (gotta try this out when I get a chance)

It happen immediately after you delete it.  You'll see that the secret for the new default service account is different from the one you deleted previously
